# ¿Como establecer fechas relativas usando PL/SQL?

Tags: base-de-datos, plsql, date

¿Como puedo establecer fechas relativas usando PL/SQL?

Por ejemplo:
Debo de cargar información en una tabla resumen del periodo 15 del  mes pasado y el 16 del mes en curso. ¿Existira alguna forma de establecer ese periodo sin necesidad de usar fechas fijas y usar fechas relativas?

Por ejemplo:
No establecer  con un 《 where periodo  between 15/12/2019  and  16/01/2020 》 sino que ese query  se pueda correr dinamicamente cada mes sin necesidad de "quemar las fechas(periodo)"

De antemano gracias al que me 《me pueda iluminar la lógica》

Comment: Tomando como base la fecha actual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes poner lo siguiente:

```
where periodo between sysdate-30 and sysdate
```

Eso te haría que el periodo vaya entre la fecha actual y 30 días menos.

Ahora, si lo que quieres es que sea exactamente el 15 del mes anterior y el 16 del mes en curso, haría una función, que retorne una fecha, y la función tomaría el `sysdate` validaría qué tal alejado está del 16, le sumo o le resto dependiendo de esa distancia, y a la fecha resultante le resto 30, así lo podrías usar algo como:

```
where periodo between funcionFecha(2) and funcionFecha(1)
```

Donde 2 y 1 serían parámetros para saber si retorna la fecha final (16 del mes) o fecha inicial (fecha inicial - 30).